fecth API cannot load due to access control checks when downloading a json file
I have a Nextjs 14 application and the requests are made on the same origin. I experience some odd behavior when downloading json files in safari(IOS). I am using swr and it re-fetches automatically when the download is starting. Requests made by swr fail with this error:
Fetch API cannot load url due to access control checks.
This is the fetcher used by swr:
export const fetcher = async (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => {
    try {
        console.log("DEBUG_A");
        const response = await fetchWithNoCache(...args);
        console.log("DEBUG_B", {status: response.status, ok: response.ok});
        if ( !response.ok ) {
            let errorMessage = Dictionary.failedToFetchData;

            try {
                errorMessage = (await response.json()).result;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("DEBUG_C", {error});
            }
            throw new CustomHttpRequestError(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log("DEBUG_D");
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("DEBUG_E", error);
        throw error;
    }
}

export const fetchWithNoCache = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => {
    let [url, options] = args;
    console.log("DEBUG_1", {url, options});
    const headers = options?.headers ?? {};
    options = {
        ...options,
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            ...headers,
        }
    };
    console.log("DEBUG_2");
    return fetch(url, options);
}

This is the Next.js route handler:
export async function GET(request: Request, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    const session = await validateRequest();
    if ( !session.valid ) {
        return new NextResponse(null, { status: 401 });
    }
    const { id } = params;
    try {
        const service = createStyleService('route:styles');
        const data = await service.get(id);
        const filename = createStyleFilename(data, 'json')
        const stream = createReadableStreamFromJSON(JSON.parse(data.data_draft));
        return new Response(stream, {
          status: 200,
          headers: new Headers({
            "content-disposition": `attachment; filename=${filename}`,
            "content-type": 'application/json',
            "cache-control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
        })});
    } catch (error: any) {
        const status = (error instanceof InvalidInputError) ? 400 : 500;
        return new Response(null, { status });
    }
}

The code used to fetch the data inside the component:
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(getStylesUrl(), fetcher);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (error) {
            console.log('error', error)

            ...
        }
    }, [error])

The download is performed when clicking on an  html element:
<a href={`/api/styles/${style.id}/json/download`} download>
    Download JSON
</a>

The issue only appears when downloading JSONs on Safari (IOS). Other file formats do not cause the fetch requests performed by swr to fail. I have tried to modify the requests headers, but I think it might be related to how safari handles JSON downloads on IOS.
How can I fix these requests?
From the logs you can see how the requests fail the first time but the second time they work, probably when the download is finished:

